# Base path for theme stylesheets?

Tags: theming

I'm running Drupal from a subdirectory, not the root. Everytime I move my css files from my `/test` subdirectory to `/live` the urls in the stylesheet have to be changed. For example:

```
background-image: url(/test/sites/all...
```

has to be renamed

```
background-image: url(/live/sites/all...
```

Is there a setting, or something, that can inform Drupal of the base path for my css files?

Thanks.

Comment: You could do a htaccess rewrite. Or use sass to prefix your path.

Comment: Thanks. It's only a quick find and replace so it doesn't really justify going to such lengths. I was hoping there was a setting I could change in the UI, or a hook that could go in template.php.